# Is there a way to truncate field data

Tags: jq

I have some fields that are really long, but I just want to see the beginning of them. Is there a way to truncate a field to only the first X characters?

Answer (score 33):

If you mean by trimming long strings, sure.  Figure out which strings to trim then trim them.

e.g., trimming a string to the first 10 characters

```
$ echo '"12345678901234567890"' | jq '.[0:10]'
```

Read, take the first 0-10 characters of the string.

Comment: Somewhat confusing is that in this case **the leading dot is required** by jq's *Array/String Slice Filter* even after a pipe.  E.g., this `mystring | .[0:4]` instead of this: `mystring | [0:4]`.  I think the reason is that brackets otherwise designate an output array.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to recursively trim all strings:

```
.. |= (if type == "string" then .[0:2] else . end)
```

For example, if the input is:

```
{"a": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
 "b": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
 "c": ["ddddddddddddddd"]
}
```

the output (compacted) would be:

```
{"a":"aa","b":"bb","c":["dd"]}
```

Comment: This is `jq language` and not `bash`, but it is close to bash except for the `end` which is `fi` in bash. Where do I put `jq` as in the example seen from Jeff?

Comment: @Timo you pipe the data through jq, e.g. `cat input.json | jq '.. |= (if type == "string" then .[0:2] else . end)' `